# How (and when?) to remove a Session scoped bean in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

Background: I have a JSF 2.0 application using MyFaces. Using this application, the users will create a complex "Widget" by going through a number of different JSF pages. I am storing the managed bean in the session scope, and the properties get filled in as the user goes through each page.  Once they are done assembling the "widget", they would then want to create a brand new "widget" and repeat the process.  My question is, how do I completely (and safely) remove the managed bean from the session without disrupting the JSF lifecycle?

I have seen other responses for similar questions suggesting that you can invalidate the session, and also you can access the HttpSession through the FacesContext and remove the bean that way. I don't want the user to have to log out or in again, and I don't want to invalidate the entire session.  Assuming that I need to go through FacesContext to access the HttpSession and remove the bean, when in the JSF lifecyle is the most appropriate place to do this safely so that problems don't cascade through the rest of the cycle? I want to make sure JSF will have no problems creating a new session bean when the user starts the process of creating the next "widget".

I am also curious to understand why there isn't a mechanism in JSF to make this easier. Is there some other approach that I should be taking which is better in line with the intended JSF pattern?  I can't use View Scope here because the managed bean will go through several different pages and views before it is completed.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a single page wherein you render the multiple wizard steps conditionally.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{wizard.step == 1}">
   <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/wizard/step1.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{wizard.step == 2}">
   <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/wizard/step2.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{wizard.step == 3}">
   <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/wizard/step3.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

This way you can just use a `@ViewScoped` managed bean on this single page without much hassle.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org) has a [`<p:wizard>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/wizard.jsf) component which does almost exactly like that. You may find it useful in order to save yourself from some painful boilerplate code as to validation and such.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I think this might work in the situation I have now. In a more complex app though this might be more problematic. Is it really that much of a hassle to deal with a session bean?

Comment: I ended up using ViewScope bean on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your case can be simplified in case the widget creation data is encapsulated into single bean.
I mean

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class WidgetMaker {
  private Widget widget;

  public void makeWidget(){
   //after creating/saving widget
    widget = new Widget();
  }

  public void resetWidget(){
    //this method can be called with pre render view handler
    //call this method on the first page that starts widget creation
    //in case person leaves the widget creation in between and starts over again
    widget = new Widget();
  }
}
```

For resetWidget in view (In the first widget creation page only)

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{widgetMaker.resetWidget}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

You can take pointers and adapt accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if the enduser opens the widtget page in a new browser tab halfway the multi-step process? Surely those two tabs/windows would disturb each other.

Comment: @BalusC just answered as per description, that pitfall was obvious, agreed

Comment: In my case, I have a controller/backing bean in request scope, doing things that are often not thread safe like EntityManager activities. The session bean is injected into it.  With this design, would preRenderView be a safe place to run a method to eliminate the session bean?

Comment: @tcprogrammer can you post some code that would help, but as far as i can imagine entitymanager should be residing in a repository/dao bean that is singleton as per Spring semantics, you just use repository in service beans and never met a need to replace or put it into session scope, code sample would help may be you have used wrong scope perhaps.

Comment: @gbagga the controller bean is in request scope, while the entity/model bean is in session scope. The only code using EntityManager is in the controller bean, which is safely in request scope. This isn't a Spring application, its pure JPA (EclipseLink) with local transactions. I will see if i can create a simplified example to post here.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't used it myself yet, i would have a look at CDI's `ConversationScope`.

Comment: Right now using a servlet container and not a full J2EE container, but I'll keep it in mind for future consideration.

Comment: You can add CDI to any servlet container via the [Weld reference implementation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e4910).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with BalusC that the view scope would be the better choice in your case. I just looked into my (very old) first JSF project where I had a multipage form in session scope. Later I switched to view state for the well known reasons.

However, I did reset the session scoped bean by simply replacing the instance in the session map:

```java
MyBean newInstance = new MyBean();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
   .getSessionMap().put(beanName, newInstance);
```

with `beanName` as the bean's el name (a String).

Comment: As I mentioned in my post I knew how to access the bean in the session map, BUT, where exactly in the JSF lifecycle did you perform this action so it would be done safely?

Comment: I did it in a command button action method never caring about whether this was the correct phase.