# I wanna load JSF UI every time with Managed Bean Null?

Tags: jsf

Whenever I load JSF WebPage .. Then make Managed Bean NULL. and display.. Because I'm Using @Session Scoped. I don't want store any session content.

Comment: If you want any help, you should make your answer more easy to understand. And code / examples when fit.

Comment: @ashokhein dont forget to accept the correct answers to your questions should someone provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cdi jsr-299 rings no bell? If not these are things you should investigate. basically you can have cdi beans instead of jsf beans. Cdi offers conversationscope and that might meet your needs well.

If you use jsf2 beans you should read up on viewscope, might match your needs as well.

Finally what you want can be achieved if you do use jsf beans but it is not best practice. Code in one of the answers here: [How (and when?) to remove a Session scoped bean in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741778/how-and-when-to-remove-a-session-scoped-bean-in-jsf-2-0)

Comment: The question is terribly hard to understand, but I believe that the answer is to just use `@ViewScoped` instead. The CDI `@ConversationScoped` is only more clumsy to use.