# JSF 2 redirect to first page on back button or URL copy paste (no Authentication involved)

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, registration, servlet-filters, prerenderview

I have a JSF 2.0 application that is used for creating accounts using Self Registration. On the first page, there are fields like name, email, uid etc. Typical to any registration, we show the confirmation page, (other custom pages as well in between) and the final success page. Each page is rendered in JSF using the faces-redirect=true so there are 3-4 pages(facelets) in the entire process. In this application, I use a SessionScoped backing bean to show the middle pages/confirmation page/final page etc. After the registration is complete, I clear the SessionScope bean from session and invalidate the session.

The problem is:
The confirmation page/middle page etc. show the User details that the User entered from the first page(using the EL from the backing bean: #sessionBean.firstName etc.). So, if the User enters this URL in the browser directly (host/appName/confirmationPage.xhtml), the page loads with blank values (as the User did not go to the first page directly). Also, after the registration is complete, if the User clicks on the back button blank values show up (no-cache is explicitly set in the filter class, so cache is not used here which is the correct behavior)

How do I force the User to go to the first page if the firstName etc. is not present. i.e. when the User lands up on a page, make sure that User landed on this page only through the first page in this session?

Should a filter class be used? Or should a prerenderview event be used to check for blank values and redirect them to the first page? There is no "User Login" here as there is no authentication. I believe this is a common use-case and I would like to know if there is any best practice in JSF

Comment: possible duplicate of [How (and when?) to remove a Session scoped bean in JSF 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741778/how-and-when-to-remove-a-session-scoped-bean-in-jsf-2-0)

Comment: [PrimeFaces wizard](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/wizard.jsf) is what you need